# What is a good debugging procedure to fix undefined citations?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, debugging

I have a small example that has undefined citations problems. I want to solve these problems, but I've encountered similar problems before and don't have a good debugging procedure for them (I've usually ended up rewriting the references or something), so I would value recommendations on an approach to debugging these problems.

I've got the following files in a directory:

- test.tex
- references.bib
- references.tex

`test.tex` contains the following:

```
\documentclass[american, a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}        

This is a reference~\cite{Tianjun_1}. This is another reference~\cite{McCulloch_Pitts_1}.

\include{references}

\end{document}
```

`references.tex` contains the following:

```
\renewcommand\bibname{references}
\bibliography{references}
```

`references.bib` contains the following:

```
@article{Tianjun_1,
    title={Distinguishing the Color Octet Axial-Vector-like Particle for Top Quark Asymmetry via Color Flow Method at the LHC},
    author={Li Tianjun, L. and Xia, W. and You-kai, W. and Shou-hua, Z.},
    note="{arXiv:1306.3586}",
    month={June},
    year={2013},
}
@article{McCulloch_Pitts_1,
    year={1943},
    journal={The Bulletin of Mathematical Biophysics},
    volume={5},
    number={4},
    title={A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity},
    publisher={Kluwer Academic Publishers},
    author={McCulloch, W. S. and Pitts, W.},
    pages={115--133},
}
```

I compile `test.tex` using the following commands:

```
rm *.log *.blg *.bbl *.lot *.lof *.toc *.aux
latex test.tex
bibtex test
latex test.tex
latex test.tex
```

When I compile, I get such messages as the following:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Tianjun_1' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `McCulloch_Pitts_1' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.
```

The resulting document contains question marks where reference numbers should be. I want to solve my specific problems and get the references to appear, but I would value guidance on the debugging process.

Comment: \newcount\citecount\citecount=0\let\oldcite\cite\def\cite#1{\advance\citecount1\typeout{This is citation \the\citecount with identifier #1}\oldcite{#1}} will output stuff in console

Comment: The `.blg` file is the place to look for BibTeX warnings. Here, you don't seem to have a `\bibliographystyle` line, so BibTeX will give up (`I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ...`). If that's true in the real do it will be the issue.

Comment: you say you do `latex test` but `bibtex report` one of those is wrong, you need the same name in both cases/

Comment: @1010011010 Thank you for that nifty trick for debugging.

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thanks for your guidance on that. So, ```.blg``` is a good place to look for BibTeX problems. Yes, I had removed a custom BibTeX style for the purposes of clarity and didn't include a standard one. Thanks

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks for spotting that typographical error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@d2dp As noted above you needed a `\bibliographystyle` line.  I removed the American from the class options as it is not used in report.

Finally you can surf for `bibtex styles`.  Here is a typical find: http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/ALPHA/bibstylescompared.pdf

```
\begin{filecontents}{references.tex}
\renewcommand\bibname{references}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{references}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Tianjun_1,
    title={Distinguishing the Color Octet Axial-Vector-like Particle for Top Quark Asymmetry via Color Flow Method at the LHC},
    author={Li Tianjun, L. and Xia, W. and You-kai, W. and Shou-hua, Z.},
    note="{arXiv:1306.3586}",
    month={June},
    year={2013},
}
@article{McCulloch_Pitts_1,
    year={1943},
    journal={The Bulletin of Mathematical Biophysics},
    volume={5},
    number={4},
    title={A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity},
    publisher={Kluwer Academic Publishers},
    author={McCulloch, W. S. and Pitts, W.},
    pages={115--133},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}        

This is a reference~\cite{Tianjun_1}. This is another reference~\cite{McCulloch_Pitts_1}.

\include{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear example. I learned about the ```filecontents``` approach too, so thanks!